# Magento 2:Admin tab and grid

Tags: magento2, admin, tabs

I want to enable a admin tab 'Products' once after saving data in other three tabs. That tab should contain a product grid(product name and product id).

The product collection in the grid should be filtered on the basis of an attribute code. For example in Manage Products if I have selected red for attribute color. That product should be displayed in grid.

How is it possible? Please help.

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: My version 2.1.3

Comment: The Grid likes Upsell, Crossell, Related product?

Comment: I just want to get the details about the products in tab which have been selected in Manage products section.For eg:I have created an attribute color and it has some option values.For a product 'A' I have selected option value blue and saved the product.In my custom module tab I have dropdown field that list the option values of attribute color. If I select color blue and save,the 'Products' tab should appear and the grid contents should be name and id of product 'A'.